# Azure Functions in .NET Core 3.1 : dependency Injection error

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1

I have migrated some Azure Functions from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 and implemented the dependency injections for my function's class and I am getting this error:

> Executed 'GetDataAsync' (Failed, Id=1f90c913-4385-4ef9-9f40-09e413191ba9, Duration=222ms)
> [2022-03-30T19:43:43.143Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost:
> Registered factory delegate returns service is not assignable to ambiently scoped container with {no name, Parent={no name}}.
> [2022-03-30T19:43:43.268Z] An unhandled host error has occurred.
> [2022-03-30T19:43:43.272Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Registered factory delegate returns service  is not assignable to ambiently scoped container with {no name, Parent={no name}}.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Common1" Version="1.0.33.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Common2" Version="3.12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.1.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: there isn't enough info here. can we see how you're registering your services? Also, have you made sure your packages are also upgraded? Could you provide more code.

Comment: Could you provide .csproj code and the function code written the DI to check the appropriate versions of NuGet Packages and Code suitable when migrating from 2.2 to 3.

Comment: Does [this](https://mikaberglund.com/dryioc-containerexception-in-azure-functions-application-when-deployed-to-azure/) help?

Comment: I have just shared .csproj file. @Steven, I have tried that link. It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

**Please check if the below steps help to**:

As following this [medium article](https://medium.com/@therealjordanlee/dependency-injection-in-azure-functions-v3-7148d0574dfc), I resolved the same error when adding the dependency injections to one of the Azure Functions Project v3 migrated from .NET 2.2:

The error I got:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Registered factory delegate returns service Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory is not assignable to container. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

In `Startup.cs` File, registered the `Serilog` logger in the `builder.Services.AddLogging` method and `Serilog Logger` is created with its own instance and all the configurations.

```cs
// Startup.cs - Registering a third party logging provider
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(logger));
```

Also, please refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) helps you regarding the usage of Dependency Injection in .NET Azure Functions.